# SQL sum 2 different column by different condtion then subtraction and add

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp, where-clause

what I am trying is kind of complex, I will try my best to explain.

I achieved the first part which is to sum the column by hours.

**example**

```
ID         TIMESTAMP          CUSTAFFECTED
1     10-01-2013 01:00:23       23
2     10-01-2013 03:00:23       55
3     10-01-2013 05:00:23       2369
4     10-01-2013 04:00:23       12
5     10-01-2013 01:00:23       1
6     10-01-2013 12:00:23       99
7     10-01-2013 01:00:23       22
8     10-01-2013 02:00:23       3
```

**output would be**

```
      Hour          TotalCALLS   CUSTAFFECTED
  10/1/2013 01:00       3         46        
  10/1/2013 02:00       1         3
  10/1/2013 03:00       1         55
  10/1/2013 04:00       1         12
  10/1/2013 05:00       1         2369
  10/1/2013 12:00       1         99
```

**Query**

```
    SELECT   TRUNC(STARTDATETIME, 'HH24') AS hour, 
           COUNT(*) AS TotalCalls,
           sum(CUSTAFFECTED) AS CUSTAFFECTED
    FROM     some_table
    where STARTDATETIME >= To_Date('09-12-2013 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and
          STARTDATETIME <= To_Date('09-13-2013 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and
GROUP BY TRUNC(STARTDATETIME, 'HH')
```

**what I need**
what I need sum 2 queries and group by timestamp/hour. 2nd query is exactly same as first but just the where clause is different.

**2nd query**

```
SELECT   TRUNC(RESTOREDDATETIME , 'HH24') AS hour, 
     COUNT(*) AS TotalCalls, 
     SUM(CUSTAFFECTED) AS CUSTRESTORED
FROM     some_table
where RESTOREDDATETIME >= To_Date('09-12-2013 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and
      RESTOREDDATETIME <= To_Date('09-13-2013 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
GROUP BY TRUNC(RESTOREDDATETIME , 'HH24')
```

so I need to subtract custaffected - custrestoed, and display tht total.

I added link to excel file. http://goo.gl/ioo9hg

Thanks

Comment: Please include complete sql queries and table schema for `some_table`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I updated it.

Comment: @CharlesBretana what is table schema, sample data?

Comment: Table schema, is list of column names and datatypes.  Also, Should not first output column in first query reference `STARTDATETIME` and in second query, `RESTOREDDATETIME`  ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that correct sql is in question text, try this:

```
SELECT TRUNC(STARTDATETIME, 'HH24') AS hour,        
   COUNT(*) AS TotalCalls, 
   Sum(case when RESTOREDDATETIME is null Then 0 else 1 end) RestoredCount,
   Sum(CUSTAFFECTED) as CUSTAFFECTED,
   Sum(case when RESTOREDDATETIME is null Then 0 else CUSTAFFECTED end) CustRestored,
   SUM(CUSTAFFECTED) - 
    Sum(case when RESTOREDDATETIME is null Then 0 else CUSTAFFECTED end) AS CUSTNotRestored
FROM     some_table
where STARTDATETIME >= To_Date('09-12-2013 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
   and STARTDATETIME <= To_Date('09-13-2013 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
GROUP BY TRUNC(STARTDATETIME, 'HH24')
```

Comment: How are you getting custrestored?, you would have to use `RESTOREDDATETIME` in where clause to find the restored for given hour then you subtract restored from start.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to do this and had to play with it some to get it to work.

The challenge is to get the results of one query to link over to another query all inside the same query and then manipulate the returned value of a field so that the value in a given field in one query's resultset, call it FieldA, is subtracted from the value in a field in a different resultset, call it FieldB.  It doesn't matter if the subject values are the result of an aggregation function like COUNT(...); they could be any numeric field in a resultset needing grouping or not.  Looking at values from aggregation functions just means you need to adjust your query logic to use GROUP BY for the proper fields.  The approach requires creating in-line views in the query and using those as the source of data for doing the subtraction.

A red herring when dealing with this kind of thing is the MINUS operator (assuming you are using an Oracle database) but that will not work since MINUS is not about subtracting values inside a resultset's field values from one another, but subtracting one set of matching records found in another set of records from the final result set returned from the query.  In addition, MINUS is not a SQL standard operator so your database probably won't support it if it isn't Oracle you are using.  Still, it's awfully nice to have around when you need it.

OK, enough prelude.  Here's the query form you will want to use, taking for example a date range we want grouped by YYYY-MM:

```
select inlineview1.year_mon, (inlineview1.CNT - inlineview2.CNT) as finalcnt from
 (SELECT TO_CHAR(*date_field*, 'YYYY-MM') AS year_mon, count(*any_field_name*) as CNT
  FROM *schemaname.tablename*
   WHERE *date_field* > TO_DATE('*{a year}-{a month}-{a day}*', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
    *date_field* < TO_DATE('*{a year}-{a month}-{a day}*', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and 
    *another_field* = *{value_of_some_kind}* -- ... etc. ...
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(*date_field*, 'YYYY-MM')) inlineview1,
 (SELECT TO_CHAR(*date_field*, 'YYYY-MM') AS year_mon, count(*any_field_name*) as CNT
  FROM *schemaname.tablename* 
   WHERE *date_field* > TO_DATE('*{a year}-{a month}-{a day}*', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
     *date_field* < TO_DATE('*{a year}-{a month}-{a day}*', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
     *another_field* = *{value_of_some_kind}* -- ... etc. ...
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(*date_field*, 'YYYY-MM')) inlineview2
WHERE
inlineview1.year_mon = inlineview2.year_mon
order by *either or any of the final resultset's fields* -- optional
```

A bit less abstractly, an example wherein a bookseller wants to see the net number of books that were sold in any given month in 2013.  To do this, the seller must subtract the number of books retruned for refund from the number sold.  He does not care when the book was sold, as he feels a returned book represents a loss of a sale and income statistically no matter when it occurs vs. when the book was sold.  Example:

```
select bookssold.year_mon, (bookssold.CNT - booksreturned.CNT) as netsalescount from
 (SELECT TO_CHAR(SALE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') AS year_mon, count(TITLE) as CNT
  FROM RETAILOPS.ACTIVITY
   WHERE SALE_DATE > TO_DATE('2012-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
    SALE_DATE < TO_DATE('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and 
    OPERATION = 'sale'
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(SALE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM')) bookssold,
 (SELECT TO_CHAR(SALE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') AS year_mon, count(TITLE) as CNT
  FROM RETAILOPS.ACTIVITY
   WHERE SALE_DATE > TO_DATE('2012-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
    SALE_DATE < TO_DATE('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and 
    OPERATION = 'return'
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(SALE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM')) booksreturned
WHERE
bookssold.year_mon = booksreturned.year_mon
order by bookssold.year_mon desc
```

Note that to be sure the query returns as expected, the two in-line views must be equijoined based as shown above on some criteria, as in:

```
bookssold.year_mon = booksreturned.year_mon
```

or the subtraction of the counted records can't be done on a 1:1 basis, as the query parser will not know which of the records returned with a grouped count value is to be subtracted from which.  Failing to specifiy an equijoin condition will yield a Cartesian join result, probably not what you want (though you may inded want that).  For example, adding 'booksreturned.year_mon' right after 'bookssold.year_mon' to the returned fields list in the top-level select statement in the above example and eliminating the

```
bookssold.year_mon = booksreturned.year_mon
```

criteria in its WHERE clause will produce a working query that does the subtraction calculation on the CNT values for the YYYY-MM values in the first two columns of the resultset and shows them in the third column.  Handy to know this if you need it, as it has solid application in business trends analysis if you can compare sales and returns not just within a given atomic timeframe but as compared across such timeframes in a 1:N fashion.